# Media queries breakpoints not accurate

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am creating media queries for a page but I'm having a problem in getting them to break at exactly the points specified in my media queries.

For example I have:

```
@media all and (max-width:1000px) {
    header nav ul.nav_items li a {
        padding:15px 10px 15px;        
    }
}
```

But when I use Chrome and open the dev tools, and observe the viewport/width of the browser, the CSS rules take effect at somewhere around 1226px. Why aren't the CSS rules being applied at exactly 1000px?

Here is a jsfiddle of my HTML/CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/at68m0zp/

Comment: Do you have meta view port tag in header ?

Comment: Yes, I have this tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: `@media all and (max-width:900px)` ?

Comment: Gonna say we'd have to ***see*** it not working. A Demo or Link would be useful.

Comment: just updated with a jsfiddle

Comment: @somethinghere I posted the generated CSS from SASS

Comment: @Tony54 Jup, misread because of the styling used. Sorry about that. Added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By moving the media query to the *end* of your CSS file, you will make it override the set values. The later something appears (and the more specific it gets) the more preference it receives. Because your query is at the start of the file, any changes to your header nav's display property later does not get applied. Please not that media queries do not increase specificity or get any special treatment, they just get ignored until they are in the range defined by them.

So there is probably a snippet later in your file with a max-width of, say, 1000px. Because it comes after your 900px one but the screen size makes both valid, the 1000px one takes effect.

*I had a snippet with the changes but because you posted your entire HTML and CSS it is too long to post here. Trust me, it works if you move it to the end*

Comment: @Tony54 Is it because their answers are phrased as questions that should be in comments...? I will not be petty about this, you do what you want, but I honestly believe that the other answers don't explain anything. But thats just me :)

Answer (score 0):

`326px` difference is definately not 'inaccuracy'. Something is broken here big time. I might guess that you have more media queries and mistaken `min-width` `max-width` setups somewere.

The best to check what is actually going on:

1. Firefox - hit F12 (or open Dev Tools when on Mac)
2. Go to 'Style Editor' in Dev Tools top bar
3. Column on the right shows list of @media rules (breaking points)

Have fun and good luck with debug.